# is it possible to get and display list item fields dynamically with SPD workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, jsom

I have a custom list with a column that has a look-up field. I want to populate dynamically some values from another list to a column of the current list on the basis of  what is chosen in the look-up field.

For example if i choose "F.Sc Pre Eng. Part 01" in Program Name the related courses should be displayed dynamically in Course column.
[image: Student List Example]

Note: Currenltly i'm using Set field action in my workflow. But it set value after the list item is created and i want run time dynamic values in Course column.

[image: SPD 2013 workflow]

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just select Courses as an additional column in the lookup for Program Name?

Comment: You can't use workflow to solve this problem as it always triggers after the record is saved. It will have to be JavaScript on a SharePoint page I think.

Comment: @PerJakobsen because the values that i want to save in course column are already look-up from another list

Comment: @unibod50 infopath has a way to do this but i'm looking for a method in SPD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, since the workflow action cannot dynamically populate the field based on the selection of look up field, I recommend you using code with SPServices in the Newform.aspx and Editform.aspx page in SharePoint Designer.
Edit the form page in advanced mode and add the script below: In my test,

Current List: list5, Columns: Project Name, Course.

Information list: list4, Columns:ProjectName, course.

Please change the relevant column name and list name for your list.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var ID；
$('select[title="Project Name"]').change(function(){
ID =  $('select[title="Project Name"] option:selected').val();
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "list4",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='course' /></ViewFields>",
    CAMLQuery:  "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Counter'>" + ID + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        var course = $(this).attr("ows_course");
            $('input[title="Course"]').val(course);
          });
        }

  });
  });
});
</script>
```

[image]